# When is square root of transpose and transpose of square root of a matrix are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Square root of transpose and transpose of square root of a matrix.

$B^{\frac{1}{2}^T}=B^T{^{\frac{1}{2}}} $ (This is not true in general.)

where $B$ is symmetric.

But what are the instances where this would hold?

Comment: But if $B$ is symmetric, then $B^T=B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ which has no eigenvalues in $]\infty ,0]$; in particular, $A$ is invertible.
Let $\log$ be the principal value of the logarithm, that is,

$\log: re^{i\theta}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus (]-\infty,0])\mapsto \log(r)+i\theta$, where $\theta\in ]-\pi,\pi[$.

We extend the definition as follows (cf. [1], Matrix of functions, Higham):

if the Jordan form of $A$ is $A=PUP^{-1}$ with $U=diag(\lambda_kI_{i_k}+J_{i_k})$ ($J_k$ being the nilpotent Jordan form of dimension $k$), then

$\log(A)=Pdiag(\log(\lambda_kI_{i_k}+J_{i_k}))P^{-1}$ with $\log(\lambda_kI_{i_k}+J_{i_k}))=\log(\lambda_k)+\log(I_{i_k}+1/\lambda_kJ_{i_k})$.

Finally $A^{1/2}=e^{1/2\log(A)}$ is the unique square root whose spectrum lies in the open right plane.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. With the above defintion, ${A^{1/2}}^T={A^T}^{1/2}$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. One has $A^{1/2}=\dfrac{2}{\pi} A\int_0^{+\infty}(t^2I+A)^{-1}dt$ ([1] p. 133). Then ${A^{1/2}}^T=\dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{+\infty}(t^2I+A^T)^{-1}A^Tdt={A^T}^{1/2}$ because the integral is a polynomial in $A^T$.  $\square$

Comment: This is for A positive definite? For positive definite A, the square root is unique and is symmetric. So this is that proof? Thank you

Comment: According to the definition, the result is valid for any complex matrices that have no eigenvalues in $]-\infty,0]$. If $A$ is real, then $A^{1/2}$ is real. On the contrary, $diag(-1,1)$ admits no real square roots.

Comment: By $]-\infty,0]$, do you mean the closed left plane?

Comment: No. It's the set of $\leq 0$ real numbers.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how exactly you define *the* square root of $B$, but if $A$ is *a* square root of $B$, then $A^2=B$. Transposing that equation gives $(A^T)^2 = B^T$, thus $A^T$ is *a* square root of $B^T$. Whether it is *the* square root of $B^T$ depends on how you select *the* square root among all possible square roots of $B^T$.

Comment: This answer is perfect. :)

Comment: "Whether it is the square root of $B^T$ depends on how you select the square root among all possible square roots of B." This is it. Thank You

Comment: @JohnHughes: Actually it was demonstrably not perfect, since it had a typo (twice; now fixed) that even made it incorrect. But thank you.